# What is setApplicationDestinationPrefixes being used for?

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I followed a tutorial to implement websockets in my Java Spring application.
It is working fine so far but I really would like to understand what this is used for:

```
config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
```

My whole config looks like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
  }
}
```

I basically just don't understand the given explanations in spring docs / the tut - e.g.

> ... it designates the "/app" prefix for messages that are bound for @MessageMapping-annotated methods.

Answer (score 12):

setApplicationDestinationPrefixes is used as prefix to message mapping while sending messages from client using STOMP.
So if your client sending data using STOMP for @MessageMapping("add") then the stompClient.send("/app/add"..)

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: But how would you distinguish prefixes between different controllers or single controller methods? I mean how would you associate this or that prefix with the specific method in a controller if you have several methods in your controller each going with @MessageMapping?

Comment: @AndreyM.Stepanov answering your comment for legacy. If you want to have a different prefix per controller you can simply set a class level `@MessageMapping("app")`. In the example above this would allow you to remove `config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")`.

Answer (score 11):

In other words, it has no real meaning other than assuring that all messages that will be received on the server and are having one of the prefixes from the list set by `setApplicationDestinationPrefixes` will be interpreted by one of your methods that you annotated with `@MessageMapping` annotation.

Simpler put - methods annotated by `@MessageMapping` will be triggered only if the message has one of the prefixes in the list.

Comment: This is the explanation I needed. Cheers Victor!

Comment: Is it also possible to call such method with `SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/app/add", "hello");` from the server?

Comment: how would you distinguish prefixes between different controllers or single controller methods? I mean how would you associate this or that prefix with the specific method in a controller if you have several methods in your controller each going with @MessageMapping?

Comment: actually I do not understand what was the motivation to remove prefixes from the attribute of @MessageMapping - why not to have full message paths (or are they called 'destinations'?)

Answer (score 1):

setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app") - used to

> Configure one or more prefixes to filter destinations targeting
> application annotated methods. When messages are processed, the
> matching prefix is removed from the destination in order to form the
> lookup path. This means annotations should not contain the destination
> prefix.[1](https://helptechcommunity.wordpress.com/2020/01/28/websocket-chat-application-using-spring-boot-and-react-js/)

reference:- https://helptechcommunity.wordpress.com/2020/01/28/websocket-chat-application-using-spring-boot-and-react-js/